# Sync Microsoft Dynamics CRM Data with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Good afternoon all,

I've been tasked with the integration of our Company's Microsoft Dynamics CRM and SharePoint 2013. I have found plenty of helpful ways to pull SharePoint data TO the CRM, and I've also been successful in pushing data from the CRM to SharePoint, although the latter is not working as desired.

**CRM Test Data:**
[image: CRM Test Data]

**When pushed to SharePoint, displays like so:**
[image]

My goal is to sync our accounts and contacts from the CRM to a list on SharePoint as list items. Thus far I've only been able to push the data and create folders on the SharePoint with the same names (See above). The SP list can be as simple as just the Name field for Accounts.

My other problem is the fact that I have to manually push the CRM data to the SharePoint list when creating new accounts on the CRM. Is there a way to automate this? First thoughts are a workflow on the CRM that syncs when a new account is created.

**TL/DR Summary:**

- Need the CRM to create list items within a matching list on
  SharePoint
- SharePoint only needs to have read abilities from the CRM
- CRM data needs to refresh/sync to the SharePoint list automatically

Comment: You can do it through a Plugin or a Custom workflow.

Comment: Do you by chance have an example I might glean some information from? As I mentioned, I have not found an abundance of material/documentation detailing what I wish to do.  

I have started fleshing out a workflow ("process" for the CRM) although I am at something of a standstill and don't know how to progress.   
Any recommended plugins that may also achieve the desired results are also welcomed!

Comment: https://meghshyam.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/create-folder-in-sharepoint-site-from-crm-record-via-plugin/

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/23192/37271

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated CRM online with both On-Premise sharepoint and Office 365 using BCS and an OData wrapper that consumes the CRM web services. what exactly is your requirements with the integration? to just have a list of accounts/other data, or something more?

Edit:
in this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2013/05/13/connecting-sharepoint-online-and-crm-online-using-bcs-2013-edition.aspx

He references the CRM SDK where there is a sample webappwalkthrough solution. set it up to your needs and deploy it somewhere. then create a sharepoint hosted app in visual studio and create an external content type in there pointing to the odata source you just created. extract the ect file out of the project and upload it to the BCS service application and create an external list that uses that external content type. you should be good to go. there are a lot of steps so reply if you get stuck.

Comment: Correct, the only goal here is just to keep the existing CRM list of account names in sync with a matching list (containing only a single-line "name" field for the account names) our onsite SharePoint server.

Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for chiming in on my topic!

Comment: What if you used an external list instead of syncing lists? do you have any search requirements? or do you just simply need a list of accounts accessible in SharePoint?

Comment: It does not need to be searchable, it simply needs to be an up-to-date list of accounts from the CRM accessible within the SharePoint.